# Compare two datasets for date timestamps that overlap and place them in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Background**

I am wanting to compare the date and timestamps between two datasets to see if some of the date timestamps from df1 overlap with any of the date timestamps from df2. For the times that are overlapping, I would like to remove these and place in a separate list.

here are the two datasets: df1 and df2

```
df1

start                       end     

5/11/2020 1:30:00 PM        5/11/2020 2:00:00 PM
5/11/2020 2:30:00 PM        5/11/2020 3:34:00 PM




df2

connect                     stop   

5/11/2020 1:45:00 PM        5/11/2020 2:15:00 PM
5/12/2020 10:00:00 AM       5/12/2020 10:30:00 AM
```

**Desired output**

```
df3 (contains the date timestamps that are overlapping)

start                  end                    connect                 stop   

5/11/2020 1:45:00 PM   5/11/2020 2:15:00 PM   5/11/2020 1:30:00 PM    5/11/2020 2:00:00 PM



df4(contains the date timestamps that are not overlapping)


start                   end                    connect                 stop  

5/11/2020 2:30:00 PM   5/11/2020 3:34:00 PM    5/12/2020 10:00:00 AM   5/12/2020 10:30:00 AM
```

**What I have tried**

I researched and modified this particular code below, however, things get a bit tricky when trying to 
   incorporate two datasets

```
s1=df1.start.values
s2=df1.end.values
sum(np.minimum(s2[:,None],s2)-np.maximum(s1[:,None],s1)>0)>1
```

I could also work with a merge

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,
                   left_on='Connect',
                   right_on='start',
                   tolerance = pd.Timedelta(''),
                   direction='nearest')
```

**Structure of df1 and df2**

```
df1
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
start    2 non-null object
end      2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)



df2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
connect    2 non-null object
stop       2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `numpy` broadcast , so let us start build the relation from there

```
s1=df1.start.values
s2=df1.end.values
s=df2.connect.values[:,None]
idxmatch=(((s1-s)/np.timedelta64(1, 's')<=0)&((s2-s)/np.timedelta64(1, 's')>=0)).dot(df2.index.values+1)

df2.index=idxmatch-1

over=df1.join(df2,how='inner')
```

Comment: Let me try this, thank you. So this is essentially an inner join as well?

Comment: @Lynnette yes, Just in case you need the not match from df1, so change the how to left , the not overlap items in the same df seems like not make sense ...

Comment: Hi @yoben_s, will this still work if the dataframes are not the same length? I am getting a dim error on my large dataset